# client failure detection in client-server systems (distributed)

Tags: java, web-applications, client-server, distributed

Assume a distributed communication system where client and server communicate via a stateless channel.
The client sends requests to the server and the server does processing and keeps internal records for each client.
Server sends back notifications to the clients as various events happen to the system, as needed.
The notification mechanism depends on the internal records.
My question is, what is the standard appoach in distributed computing to handle the client failures?
I.e. in this context, assume that the client process crashes or simply restarts.
The server still has the records for the client but now client and server are of sync.
As a result client will get notifications according to records created before restart. This is **undesirable**.
What is a standardized way to detect the client failures? E.g. client has restarted and previous records must be erased?
I thought of periodic callbacks to clients and if a client is not reachable, erase its records but I am not sure if this is a good idea. **[EDIT]** I thought of callbacks because, the period events send back to the client can be in very large intervals and so the client failure would not be noticable soon

Can anyone help on this? The context of my application domain is web services.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard approach varies from system to system depending to the architecture and domain. How the server finds out that the client is down? I think you don't need callbacks, since you send the notifications and can detect that the client is unreachable. For example:

1. send a notification to the client;
2. if success, goto 1;
3. else erase all the notifications in the queue for the client, set a flag to not collect events for the client.

When a client is connected:

1. unset the flag;
2. start sending notifications

Or even a simpler approach:

1. erase the notification queue for the client when it connects before initializing the conversation;
2. run a low-priority thread to erase all the notifications for all the clients which are older then X, to clean notifications for the client which will never come back.

#### Update after the original author comments

It strongly depends on how things are organized in your system. Assuming:

1. The server starts a thread (let's call it "agent") to serve a client, a thread per client.
2. The agent exits when the clients shuts down the session properly or goes down.
3. there is a private (which is not shared among agents/clients) record set for each client
4. there is a shared list of current clients which is used by another component (not an ordinary agent, let's call it "dispatcher") to distribute records for clients.

solution:
1. the server starts an agent and registers the client just connected to list of clients. The dispatcher gets notified that a new client arrived.
2. the agent consumes the records until client is connected. On client's shutdown and/or failure the agents unregisters the client and cleans the record set.

If things in your system aren't organized in the way described above, please provide some details.

Comment: @khachic:What you say is valid. But the events can be generated in fairly large intervals, so the next call back can be in quite a long period of time.So for this long period the server still has the records. That is why I initially thought of the callback. To detect client failure very fast

Comment: If I understood your architecture correctly: the low-level garbage collector thread will collect that records.

Comment: @khachik: But after how long will they be cleaned? If I wait for a notification to fail, records will remain for long time. Right?

Comment: It depends how it is organized. Please see my update in the answer and comment it.

Comment: @khachik:Your description is close to my organization.The difference is that I mostly use event queues and not so much threads. In any case in your last update, I can not see how the server detects failure. You just say:"On client's shutdown and/or failure the agents unregisters the client.." but when does this happen? How is the failure detected so that the agents unregister the client in your model?

Comment: If the servers sends the notifications via sockets, it detects the failures on socket errors. Right? If not, how the server sends the notifications?

Comment: @Khachic:Ah! No, it is over HTTP. I wrote in the post that the context is web services.

Comment: HTTP is over TCP/IP so you use sockets. If you use a third-party library, it should provide a way to detect communication errors.

Comment: @khachik:It is over TCP/IP but it is stateless. A connection can be explicitely closed since it is a request-response protocol, but the "sesion" can be considered as active. I.e. it does not imply persistent connections

Comment: How the server sends notifications? Clients request them and the server sends as a response? And the problem is how to detect that the client has gone and will not request notifications anymore? Last time I solved a similar problem in the server application I was designing. After some googling for similar architectures I decided to introduce a configuration parameter for the server which defines the max length of the queues which store data needs to be delivered to the client. You can do the same and combine it with another parameter, like timeout, to consider clients down.

Comment: @khachik: The notifications are generated by internal events. These events could be a result of a previous request, but could be a result of other activity in the system.How to use timeout?How much time server hasn't got a request? There is no restriction on clients on how they will send a request and how often

Comment: Well.. the server collects the notifications for a client in a queue. When a client comes "online" (connects to the server), the servers sets a flag to collect all the notifications for that client. After the timeout it shrinks the queue for a client to the max length coming from configuration. Every connection from a clients defers shrinking by timeout period.

Comment: @khachik:I do not understand this timeout. When does the timer start?

Comment: The timer starts, when the client is connected and a response is sent. And it starts every time the client connects.

Comment: @khachik:So when the first response to client is send the time starts. Timer value is configuration parameter. E.g. 3 mins. So 3 mins pass timer expires, then what? I am sorry but it is not clear to me what the detection mechanism is

Comment: Timer expires and delete all old notifications for the given client, leaves X notifications, X comes from the configuration.

Comment: @khachik:When is the timer reset?

Comment: Well... Client connects. Timer starts with 3m timeout. Client disconnects. 1 minute passed. Client connects. Timer starts with 3 timeout again. Client disconnects. 3 minutes passed. Server deletes all the notifications since there is no client activity during last 3 minutes.

Comment: @khachik:I think I got it!You are suggesting a watchdog timer in the server.I like the idea!But one last question. How "scalable" is this for more than 1 clients? E.g. for x clients I must have x watchdog timers for each, right? Is there a way around this?

Comment: It depends on the internal architecture of the server. For example, if you use an SQL database to store records, there can be one watcher thread for all clients, which periodically executes something like this: `DELETE FROM RECS where EXISTS (select * from CLIENTS WHERE RECS.CLIENTID = CLIENTS.ID and RECS.LASTSEEN >= 3);` (use date comparing condition for `LASTSEEN`.